# Angularjs: how to organize a big project code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have troubles in organizing AngylarJs code within big project. Here is an example similar to the architecture of angular-app (https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app).
Suppose there are 4 pages: main, details, profile, admin. These pages completelety isolated with refs to each other. In other words it's not SPA.

Here's dir struct:

```
app
---main
-----main.js - module
---details
-----details.js - module
---profile
-----profile.js - module
---admin
-----admin.js 
app.js
```

Example app.js code:

```
angular.module('app', [
    ‘main’,
    ‘details’,
    ‘profile’,
    ‘admin’
])
```

Then one build.js is built including common directives, services, resources, etc. That bulid.js is included on each page (main.html, details.html, profile.html, admin.html).

1. How to avoid including of unnecessary code(code for different pages included)?
2. How to avoid situation when different programmers accidently overwrite services/controllers?
3. With project grow build.js will become more heavy. Will it be a problem in future?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

Answer (score 1):

1. I use only emberjs, so i don't know the behaviour of angular. In emberjs the app is a single site application. So you need every script loaded on the start. Also i don't see any problem in loading all scripts on start.
2. Why not try a generator like [yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). This way the structure is designed by the community, and you get single generators for templates & models etc.
   Because of the given structure and the naming convention, it is easy to see if you gonna overwrite something. Also grunt takes care of your build process and minifies the output.
3. I don't think a big build.js is a problem. You can minify the output and you can compress it.